# AngulasJS HTTP Post request 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: json, angularjs, angular, http, http-status-code-401

I am using AngularJS to send the array element to my Node.js where I need to do some process. Everything works fine when the array size I am sending is small but if I try to use the array which is of 200 sizes then I get the error `431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)`. How can I resolve this issue? I cannot spit my array.

```
var data    =   JSON.stringify({
                                    input       :   $scope.input,
                                    Input1      :   $scope.Input1,
                                    Input2      :   $scope.Input2,
                                    Input3      :   $scope.Input3
                                });

$http({
    url: "/createEvents",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
    params: {data:data}
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response)   
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

I am not understanding how to fix this issue.

Comment: why are you passing data in param? `params: {data:data}`

Comment: I saw one example in StackOverflow and used the same approach. As it was working I continued to use it. Is this a wrong way of doing? Should I be using something different? I am new to Angularjs so don't know much.

Comment: FWIW, there is no charset parameter on application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http({
    url: "/createEvents",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
    data:data                                                      // check this line.
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response)   
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```